# Nested inside nested Objects with same key aggregation with another collection in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nested, nested-lists

Here I am placing example collections and expected output. I have nested modules array of objects

When I  get request from the api as student Id, course id & module id then I have to send module % if exists if not need to send % as 0

> Course collection

```
{
    "_id": "courseId1",
    "courseName": "course1",
    "isActive": true,
    "modules": [
                    {
                    "_id":"id1",
                    "name":"mod1",
                    "isActive": true
                    },
                    {
                    "_id":"id2",
                    "name":"mod2",
                    "isActive": true
                    
                    },
                    {
                    "_id":"id3",
                    "name":"mod3",
                    "isActive": true
                      "modules":[
                          {
                          "_id":"id4",
                          "name":"mod4",
                          "isActive": true
                          },
                          {
                          "_id":"id5",
                          "name":"mod5",
                          "isActive": true,
                            "modules":[
                              {
                              "_id":"id6",
                              "name":"mod6",
                              "isActive": true
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                      ]
                    }
              ]
    }
```

> Course activity collection

```
   {
    "id":"ca1",
    "studentId:"std1",
    "courseId:"courseId1",
     mProgress:[{
        "id":"ac1",
        "modId":"id5",
        "studentID":"std1",
        "progress":20  
        }
        {
        "id":"ac2",
        "modId":"id4",
        "studentID":"std1",
        "progress":10  
        }
]
}
```

If I get studentID="std1" , courseId="5f698ca6f5cd3551060d86e8" , moduleId="id3"

`I need response link below`

```
modules:
      [
            {
            "modId":"id4",
            "name:"mod4",
            "progress":10  
            },
            {
            "modId":"id5",
            "name:"mod5",
            "progress":0  
            }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by java script. 1st I found course object using mongo query after that I search for nested object(i.e modules array) by using the following function

```
    findNestedObj(keyToFind, valToFind,obj ) {
      let foundObj;
      JSON.stringify(obj , (_, nestedValue) => {
        if (nestedValue && nestedValue[keyToFind] === valToFind) {
          foundObj = nestedValue;
        }
        return nestedValue;
      });
      return foundObj;
    }

var obj = 'here your object';
findNestedObj('_id','id3',obj );
```

Then I have calculated % from that